# NSData gives NULL

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, base64

I converted an `UIImage` into `NSString` with `base64` encoding, but the data results empty. Here is my code:

```
[Base64 initialize];
    NSString *imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img:%@", [Base64 encode:UIImagePNGRepresentation(shared.image)]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:imageString];
    [shared.outputStream write:[imageData bytes] maxLength:[imageData length]];
```

I have no idea on what's going on !! If I use UTF-8 Encoding, it works just fine, but the `UIImage` `imageWithData` results null (that is not the part of the question).
What am I doing wrong?

---

By way of background, the intent here is to modify this [Ray Wenderlich demo](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) so it can send images, too.

Comment: This could probably have a more relevant title--it's more about Base64, not just NSData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You prefixed the base64 string with `img:` therefore making the string invalid base64. Remove the `img:` if you want to test decoding the string.

```
NSString *imageString = [Base64 encode:UIImagePNGRepresentation(shared.image)];
//Data should not be nil anymore.
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:imageString];
```

Also there is no reason to convert it from data, to string and then back to the same data. I assume you want the string bytes to be written as `"img:<base64 string>"`.

```
NSString *imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img:%@", [Base64 encode:UIImagePNGRepresentation(shared.image)]];
NSData *b64ImageData = [imageString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[shared.outputStream write:[b64ImageData bytes] maxLength:[b64ImageData length]];
```

Comment: The thing is that i need the img: bit because the server needs it to recognise if it is an image or just a string. So, do I need to encode the img: bit too?

Comment: See the updated answer, you should not be using the base64 method to try to decode it, you just need to get the bytes from the string.

Comment: @joe Many Base64 implementations insert newline characters periodically. Am I correct in assuming this one doesn't? If so, gga may be ok. I'd be nervous about his Python server detecting the end of the Base64 encoded string. I'd be inclined to put quotes around it just so he can confirm the end of the string.

Comment: If you are sending via HTTP POST you might consider MIME... That allows you to specify which part of your response is your image, and also has a standard way of denoting the start/end of each MIME part, solving the "when does the image end" problem.